# Regex - All PHP files without the .html extension

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex to get all files with the `.php` extension, but that don't contain `.html`.

For example:

```
foo.php (this file is ok)
foo.html.php (this file is not ok)
foo.bar (this file is not ok)
foo.bar.php (this file is ok)
```

I created this regex:

```
^(?!.*(.html))
```

But in this way I also get the files that end with `.bar` (and not only with `.php`).

Comment: Is this in a .htaccess file?

Comment: Try this `^(?!.*\.html).+\.php$)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your own regex you didn't explicitly specify the `.php` file extension, so the engine doesn't have any idea which extensions should match and which shouldn't. You are near to make it, and just a bit if modifications are needed:

```
^(?:.(?!\.html))*\.php$
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ci3Sxr/1)

Answer (score 0):

This will match the .php which is not preceded by html. I've used negative look behind to get it

```
.*(?<!\.html)\.php$
```

Explanation from regex101

`(?<!html)` Negative Lookbehind. Assert that the Regex below does not match
html matches the characters html literally (case sensitive)

`\.` matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
php matches the characters php literally (case sensitive)

`$` asserts position at the end of a line

https://regex101.com/r/TOiJQP/5

Comment: Does it match whole file name? Should it match `foo.html.bar.php`?

Comment: To match whole name it's just needed to add `.*` in the beginning of the regex

Answer (score 0):

You can make sure there is no `.html` anywhere and that it finishes with .php in the string you're trying to match with:

```
^(?!.*\.html).*\.php$
```

https://regex101.com/r/TOiJQP/4

- `^(?!.*\.html)` Negative lookahead. From the begining of the string (hence the `^`), it makes sure there is no .html anywhere in the filename
- `.*\.php$` matches a filename ending with .php

Comment: You don't need second greedy dot in your lookahead and forgot to add a literal `.` before `html`.